# Galerkin function first derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I want to find the first derivative of $U(x,y)$=$y+yx-x+yx^2$ with respect to the first $y$ term, i.e. $\frac{dU}{dy}$.

Is this is correct method for working out:
$$\frac{dU}{dx}.\frac{dx}{dy}$$
$$=\frac{dx}{dy}(y-1+2yx)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dy}(xy-x+2yx^2)$$
$$=x+2x^2$$

I know this might be basic but it's been a while and I think this might be the wrong approach.

Comment: Don't multiply  $\frac{dx}{dy}$ the same way as multiplication, it is a quantity. Keep in mind that $dx$ is not $d$ times $x$.

Comment: The best way to check an identity is to check it, which brings you to the question of what $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is...

Comment: Wait, how do you find $ \frac{dU}{dx}$ in the first place?

Comment: So I need to split the first dU/dx dx/dy further. Maybe: $$\frac{dU}{dx}.\frac{dx}{dy}$$
$$=(\frac{dU}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}).(\frac{dx}{dU}\frac{dU}{dy})$$ ?

Comment: Do you simply want the partial derivative $\partial U/\partial y$? If so, you are *really* overcomplicating things... And if not, it's not clear what you are actually asking about.

Comment: Haha oh dear. But no I don't want the partial. I want the first derivative, i.e. $\frac{dU}{dy}$.

Comment: Is $x$ a function of $y$? You seem to want the total derivative, that is $\frac{dU}{dy} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dy}$. But again, your question is not clear.

Comment: Thank you, this is hugely helpful. The question is not clear so I need to check but thanks again